# How to find shortest path on the from using coordinates - Matlab

Tags: matlab, dictionary, plot, shortest-path

I'm currently working on a map routing system for pedestrian pathway. I had found various coordinates and save it on excel. And also plotted the result of the pathway as shown in the image below.

[image]

**Edited**
I have read up on http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/ and plot the points I wanted. But I'm stuck on generating the shortest path. Example below;
[image]

My code is this:

```
M = xlsread('YCKMap.xlsx');
waypoints =[M(:,2), M(:,3)];
[lttrk,lntrk] = track('rh',waypoints,'degrees');
figure(),geoshow(lttrk,lntrk,'DisplayType','line', 'color','r');

% Place Marker
r1 = 1.382199;
c1 = 103.840638;

r2 = 1.379667;
c2 = 103.841963;

hold on
plot(c1, r1, 'g*', 'MarkerSize', 10)
plot(c2, r2, 'g*', 'MarkerSize', 10)
hold off
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2011/12/13/exploring-shortest-paths-part-5/ (and the rest of that series) will be an interesting read for you. There are however plenty ways of doing this..

Comment: Oh thanks for your info! But I'm stuck on the part which require the skeleton but I used this line;
figure(),geoshow(lttrk,lntrk,'DisplayType','line', 'color','r');
How can I convert that into so that it can me read?